# Label id in OpenCV MLData

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

As far as I understand in MLData the labels are enumerated automatically. Using the method `get_class_labels_map()` one can get the corresponding id to a label name. What is the Rule for assigning the ids? Sorting? If I have two files train.csv and test.csv can I assume, the ids are the same?

```
=== train.csv
1,2,3 hello
3,2,1 world

=== train.csv
2,2,2 world
1,1,1 hello
```

Or will 'hello' obtain in the first case the id 1 and in the second case 2?

Answer (score 0):

In new interface it seems class TrainData.
You can check how it works in source file modules/ml/src/data.cpp .